# GetSupportedPreviewSize returns reverse width and height

Tags: android, android-camera, preview

I'm using a DroidX to develop an app that uses the camera preview image.  The code I'm using is found in numerous places on the web but I noticed that the common method "getBestPreviewSize(width,height,camera.parameters)" is returning such a small size that the standard decodeYUV420SP method fails with null pointer exception.

Some debugging reveals the supportedPreviewSizes for my DroidX are:

- 144h x 176w
- 240h x 320w
- 288h x 352w
- 480h x 640w
- 480h x 720w
- 448h x 800w
- 720h x 1280w

Note that the values of height and width give a landscape perspective. This does not change with camera orientation.  The width and height of the surface passed to `getBestSupportedPreviewSizes` is 480w x 778h.

When I pass the camera.parameters to `getBestSupportedPreviewSizes()` it returns a 288 x 352 size. Here is the calling code - I apologize if the format is off but here is goes:

```
      if (!cameraConfigured) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size=getBestPreviewSize(pwidth, pheight, parameters);
        if (size!=null) {
          parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
          camera.setParameters(parameters);
          cameraConfigured=true;
        }
    }
```

`pwidth` and `pheight` are from the `surfaceChanged` callback's width and height parameters. 
I've tried    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); in onResume(). I've also put orientation("Portrait") in the the manifest - none of the 4 combinations of these attempts seem to change this behavior.

My thoughts are to simply reverse them, but it feels wrong on so many levels. Since this freely available code seems to have proven itself in so many other examples, I'm obviously approaching it wrong. Can anyone supply some insight to this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to think about the camera is in landscape mode, this means that when you are thinking about it in portrait mode, the width and height feel "flipped".

The `getBestPreviewSize( w, h, p )` function is simply a wrapper around the `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` function of `Camera.Parameters`, so the width and height passed in will not change the result of the bestPreviewSize function.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm a bit confused though. As I understand it, we pass the surface size to getBestPreviewSizes() and it returns the best fit width and height to set previewsize with. So if width is smaller than height (as in portrait mode), then the width returned will be smaller than the camera's height or the height returned will be smaller than the camera's width. So I don't understand how it doesn't affect the result of getBestPreviewSize function. What am I missing in my thinking?

Comment: Most of the getBestPreviewSizes() fns I have seen online only use the width and height to find a preview size that are a good aspect ratio. The aspect ratio is the same regardless as to whether or not height and width are flipped.

Comment: Yes, I agree Daniel, thanks. I can get the best preview size by swapping width for height to get the largest preview size possible from getBestPreviewSize.  Maybe I'm not explaining it well, but the solution seems to be to swap w & h going in to getBestPreviewSIze, but no one else appears to have this problem.

Comment: I have the problem.  And I didn't have it before when I last messed with this code a year ago.  Now getSupportedPreviewSizes() is returning landscape-oriented pairs of values (width greater than height).  What do I do so that if camera is held in portrait mode I get portrait mode values back from getSupportedPreviewSizes()?